# Scroll to and Highlight Animate Slow Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to scroll to the element(with offset from top of element), smoothly(slow) and highlight the background for a second to make it obvious what element we scrolled to(Just like Stack Overflow!_. Please let me know what I did wrong.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".scrollt0").click(function(event) {
var $target = $(this.hash);

event.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($target.offset().top-220, 'slow');
    $target.addClass('hilight');

setTimeout(function() {$target.removeClass('hilight');}, 1400);

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only animate the scrolling via jQuery. 
Try to add a css-class to the element you are trying to highlight. 
you than can remove the class with your timeout function and set the transition with css.

Comment: I'm still new to java, I edited the code the best I could from what you explained. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after some playing around.

```
$(".scrollt0").click(function(event) {
var $target = $(this.hash);

event.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top-220}, 'slow');
$target.addClass('hilight');

setTimeout(function() {$target.removeClass('hilight');}, 1000);
});
```